# Sum is not working in php mongodb

Tags: php, mongodb

Below is my mongodb data,

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("598be687c54bba05596e347e"),
        "slotid" : "248x300x250xnewdiv",
        "request_id" : "07f811ee-a8e3-4d76-9390-49f613f6bb86",
        "zoneid" : "248",
        "bidder" : "rubicon",
        "cpm" : 0.6,
        "width" : NumberInt("300"),
        "height" : NumberInt("250"),
        "is_win" : NumberInt("1"),
        "is_fail" : NumberInt("0"),
        "reponsetime" : NumberInt("294"),
        "requestdate" : "2017-08-10 04:52:25",
        "responsedate" : "2017-08-10 04:52:26"
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("598be687c54bba05596e3480"),
        "slotid" : "248x300x250xnewdiv",
        "request_id" : "07f811ee-a8e3-4d76-9390-49f613f6bb86",
        "zoneid" : "247",
        "bidder" : "rubicon",
        "cpm" : 0.6,
        "width" : NumberInt("468"),
        "height" : NumberInt("60"),
        "is_win" : NumberInt("1"),
        "is_fail" : NumberInt("0"),
        "reponsetime" : NumberInt("299"),
        "requestdate" : "2017-08-10 04:52:25",
        "responsedate" : "2017-08-10 04:52:26"
    }
```

I need to fetch data from mongodb using php ,below is my php code

```
 $res = array(
            array(
                '$group' => array(
                    "_id" => array("slotid" => '$slotid',"bidder" => '$bidder'),"total" => array('$sum' => '$cpm'),
                    ),
                ),  
        );
        $db = (new MongoDB\Client)->database;
        $resbids = $db->responsebids->aggregate($res);
        foreach($resbids as $res)
        {
        print_r($res);

    }
```

I need to group by slotid and bidder and sum cpm value , the group is working fine but cpm always shows zero, whats wrong in this code?
below is my sample result,

```
MongoDB\Model\BSONDocument Object
(
    [storage:ArrayObject:private] => Array
        (
            [_id] => MongoDB\Model\BSONDocument Object
                (
                    [storage:ArrayObject:private] => Array
                        (
                            [slotid] => 248x300x250xnewdiv
                            [bidder] => rubicon
                        )

                )

            [total] => 0
        )

)
```

Anyhelp appreciated....

Comment: Are you sure you have the same collection in your code as where you are showing the data from? Which MongoDB server version?  The server may make a difference if some of the data is actually strings.

Comment: yes the same collection present in db also, mongo db version is 3.4.6

Comment: Returns 1.2 correctly for me. simply based on the two documents above. Something is misrepresented here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have cpm in floating value u cannot add floating by $sum

Comment: yes you are correct, Is it possible to sum floating value in mongo db?

Comment: There is no such thing as a "floating value". BSON Types are `Double` and `Decimal 128` and both of course work fine with `$sum`

Comment: @neil lunn - if I change cpm value 0.6 to 1 means the sum is working and its shows total  2

Comment: @Thiyagu It works perfectly for everyone else. Think about it. It's not like you are the first person to ever store data as a `Double` ( which is what the type actually is ) so it's not the answer. It seems more likely that your actual documents are strings but you are not representing it as such in the question.